# MongoDB How to move collection from one localhost to another?

Tags: mongodb

I was using MongoDB on localhost of my Ubuntu (just for education purpose), but now, I have a new computer. So, I would like to have this collection on my new PC. What files do I need to copy to do this after installing MongoDB on a new machine ?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the new machine a linux box or a Windows PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must read [mongo backup and restore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/) this documentation explain how to backup your data base and restore.

Now you should follow this steps :

1> From your old Ubuntu systems takes back up of your DB using following command 
`mongodump --host DB name --port 27017 --out /path to save your files`
this command write data in BSON format, if you want to take only some collections from your DB then use `mongodump --collection your collection name --db DB name`

2> Now copy all above `BSON` files to your new PC and use following command to restore your old Ubuntu systems DB. 
`mongorestore --port <port number> <path to the backup>` 
before running this command you must [install](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) mongoDB.