# Restore mongodb backup archive from old version mongo

Tags: mongodb

I setup a mongodb v2.6 server and try to restore a dump generated by a v2.2 mongodump from a v2.2 server. I didn't find any useful document on this scenario.

I want to know is it OK to do it? And is there any thing I need to aware about for this specific scenario?

PS:

Someone thinks this is a duplicate of another question - [MongoDB How to move collection from one localhost to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985944/mongodb-how-to-move-collection-from-one-localhost-to-another) . And I don't know think so. The different is quite obvious. In this question, I try to figure out mongorestore's backward compatibility.

Comment: Should be fine, I usually back up the whole folder then copy/paste the data folder. Last time I did it was 2.4 to 3.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB How to move collection from one localhost to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985944/mongodb-how-to-move-collection-from-one-localhost-to-another)

Comment: @yogesh no it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worry about it. You will not encounter any problems (BSON format is the same for all mongo versions).